# Chapter header problem for bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, header-footer

I am writing my thesis using the template provided by the institute. All chapters have the correct header on the upper left corner except for the bibliography. The bibliography section has "Discussion and Conclusion", which is the previous chapter, as header. I attached a picture showing how it looks on PDF. Also, I added a the beginning and end of my document. I would really appreciate if you have any solutions. Thank you[image: Bibliography header]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,titlepage,oneside]{kumsthesis}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{apalike}
\usepackage{breakcites}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{indentfirst} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{textcomp} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption} 
\usepackage{float}
\input{macros}
 
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
Text here...
 
\chapter{Discussion and Conclusion}
Text here...
 
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{references}
 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome. // Does inserting `\newpage`, `clearpage`, `cleardoublepage` etc. help? // With non-standard classes most people here can't access them, hence can't compile and try your code ...

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  The "continued" running head is the result of the bibliography being designated as a starred (unnumbered) element.  Precede it by `\newpage \markboth{Bibliography}{Bibliography}`.  (I'm sure there is an earlierquestion that explains this.)

Comment: @MS-SPO unfortunately, it doesn't help.

Comment: @barbarabeeton it doesn't help. After the empty page, it again continues as "Discussion and Conclusion". Yes, there's an earlier question, but it didn't work for me.

Comment: @MehmetGül, kann you please verify that the same problems occure, when you change the documentclass to book? If so, everybody here can work with your code, as kumsthesis doesn't seem to be available for us.